# online shopping cart parsing error in java

Tags: java

I'm struggling with a lab in my school work. I keep getting an error:
ShoppingCartPrinter.java:29: error: reached end of file while parsing
}
^
1 error

I have looked over my code and I don't see where I missed any curly brackets.

Here is the lab details.

Create a program using classes that does the following in the zyLabs developer below. For this lab, you will be working with two different class files. To switch files, look for where it says "Current File" at the top of the developer window. Click the current file name, then select the file you need.

(1) Create two files to submit:

ItemToPurchase.java - Class definition
ShoppingCartPrinter.java - Contains main() method
Build the ItemToPurchase class with the following specifications:

Private fields

- String itemName - Initialized in default constructor to "none"
- int itemPrice - Initialized in default constructor to 0
- int itemQuantity - Initialized in default constructor to 0

Default constructor

Public member methods (mutators & accessors)

- setName() & getName() (2 pts)
- setPrice() & getPrice() (2 pts)
- setQuantity() & getQuantity() (2 pts)

(2) In main(), prompt the user for two items and create two objects of the ItemToPurchase class. Before prompting for the second item, call scnr.nextLine(); to allow the user to input a new string. (2 pts)

Ex:
Item 1
Enter the item name: Chocolate Chips
Enter the item price: 3
Enter the item quantity: 1

Item 2
Enter the item name: Bottled Water
Enter the item price: 1
Enter the item quantity: 10
(3) Add the costs of the two items together and output the total cost. (2 pts)

Ex:

TOTAL COST
Chocolate Chips 1 @ $3 = $3
Bottled Water 10 @ $1 = $10

Total: $13

Here is my code:

ShoppingCartPrinter

```
import java.until.Scanner; 

public class ShoppingCartPrinter{
   //main method
   public static void main(String[] args){
      //create object of scanner
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      //variable declaration
      int i = 0;
      String productName;
      int productPrice = 0;
      int productQuantity = 0;
      int cartTotal = 0;
      
      ItemToPurchase item1 = new ItemToPurchase();
      ItemToPurchase item2 = new ItemToPurchase();
      
      //get item 1 details
      System.out.println("Item 1");
      
      System.out.println("Enter the item name: ");
      productName = scnr.nextLine();
      item1.setName(productName);
      
      System.out.println("Enter the item price: ");
      productPrice = scnr.nextInt();
      item1.setPrice(productPrice);
      scnr.nextLine();
      
      System.out.println("Enter the item quantity: ");
      productQuantity = scnr.nextInt();
      item1.setQuantity(productQuantity);
      scnr.nextLine();
      
      scnr.nextLine();
      System.out.println("");
      
      //get item 2 details
      System.out.println("Item 2");
      
      System.out.println("Enter the item name: ");
      productName = scnr.nextLine();
      item2.setName(productName);
      
      System.out.println("Enter the item price: ");
      productPrice = scnr.nextInt();
      item2.setPrice(productPrice);
      scnr.nextLine();
      
      System.out.println("Enter the item quantity: ");
      productQuantity = scnr.nextInt();
      item2.setQuantity(productQuantity);
      scnr.nextLine();
      
      System.out.println("");
      
      //add cost of item 1 and 2 and print total
      cartTotal = (item1.getQuantity() * item1.getPrice()) + (item2.getQuantity() * item2.getPrice());
      System.out.println("TOTAL COST");
      //cart total is item 1 price * quantity + item 2 price * quantity
      //item 1 info
      int item1Total = item1.getPrice() * item1.getQuantity();
      System.out.println(item1.getName() + " " + item1.getQuantity() + " @ $" + item1.getPrice() + " = $" + item1Total);
      
      //item 2 info
      int item2Total = item2.getPrice() * item2.getQuantity();
      System.out.println(item2.getName() + " " + item2.getQuantity() + " @ $" + item2.getPrice() + " = $" + item2Total);
   
      //output total
      System.out.println("");
      System.out.print("Total: $" + cartTotal);
      
   }
}
```

ItemsToPurchase

```
public class ItemToPurchase {
   //Private fields - itemName, itemPrice, and itemQuanity
   private String itemName;
   private int itemPrice;
   private int itemQuantity;
   //Default Constructor
   public ItemToPurchase(){
      itemName = "none";
      itemPrice = 0;
      itemQuantity = 0;
   }       
   //public member methods
   public void setName(String itemName){
      this.itemName = itemName;
   }
   public String getName(){
      return itemName;
   }
   public void setPrice(int itemPrice){
      this.itemPrice = itemPrice;
   }
   public int getPrice(){
      return itemPrice;
   }
   public void setQuantity(int itemQuantity){
      this.itemQuantity = itemQuantity;
   }
   public int getQuantity(){
      return itemQuantity;
   }
   
   public void printItemPurchase() {
      System.out.println(itemQuantity + " " + itemName + " $" + itemPrice +  
                         " = $" + (itemPrice * itemQuantity));
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm presuming that import is supposed to be `java.util.Scanner`, not `until`. `String` should be capitalized in the main method. I copied your code into an IDE and do not reproduce the error mentioned -- is your code _exactly_ as indicated here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem 1: You problem is that the next int doesn't consider the new line character which goes in the input for your next read. Hence name is returned as blank.

Problem 2: You are assigning String to a int. refer: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-

The following code works fine for me:
ShoppingCartPrinter.java

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
  
  public class ShoppingCartPrinter{
     //main method
     public static void main(String[] args){
        //create object of scanner
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        //variable declaration
        int i = 0;
        String productName;
        int productPrice = 0;
        int productQuantity = 0;
        int cartTotal = 0;
        
        ItemToPurchase item1 = new ItemToPurchase();
        ItemToPurchase item2 = new ItemToPurchase();
        
        //get item 1 details
        System.out.println("Item 1");
        
        System.out.println("Enter the item name: ");
        productName = scnr.nextLine();
        item1.setName(productName);
        
        System.out.println("Enter the item price: ");
        productPrice = scnr.nextInt();
        item1.setPrice(productPrice);
        
        System.out.println("Enter the item quantity: ");
        productQuantity = scnr.nextInt();
        item1.setQuantity(productQuantity);
        
        scnr.nextLine();
        System.out.println("");
        
        //get item 2 details
        System.out.println("Item 2");
        
        System.out.println("Enter the item name: ");
        productName = scnr.nextLine();
        item2.setName(productName);
        
        System.out.println("Enter the item price: ");
        productPrice = scnr.nextInt();
        item2.setPrice(productPrice);
        
        System.out.println("Enter the item quantity: ");
        productQuantity = scnr.nextInt();
        item2.setQuantity(productQuantity);
        
        System.out.println("");
        
        //add cost of item 1 and 2 and print total
        cartTotal = (item1.getQuantity() * item1.getPrice()) + (item2.getQuantity() * item2.getPrice());
        System.out.println("TOTAL COST");
        //cart total is item 1 price * quantity + item 2 price * quantity
        //item 1 info
        int item1Total = item1.getPrice() * item1.getQuantity();
        System.out.println(item1.getName() + " " + item1.getQuantity() + " @ $" + item1.getPrice() + " = $" + item1Total);
        
        //item 2 info
        int item2Total = item2.getPrice() * item2.getQuantity();
        System.out.println(item2.getName() + " " + item2.getQuantity() + " @ $" + item2.getPrice() + " = $" + item2Total);
     
        //output total
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("Total: $" + cartTotal);
        
     }
  }
```

ItemsToPruchase.java

```
    public class ItemToPurchase {
        //Private fields - itemName, itemPrice, and itemQuanity
        private String itemName;
        private int itemPrice;
        private int itemQuantity;
    
        //Default Constructor
        public ItemToPurchase() {
            itemName = "none";
            itemPrice = 0;
            itemQuantity = 0;
        }
    
        //public member methods
        public void setName(String itemName) {
            this.itemName = itemName;
        }
    
        public String getName() {
            return itemName;
        }
    
        public void setPrice(int itemPrice) {
            this.itemPrice = itemPrice;
        }
    
        public int getPrice() {
            return itemPrice;
        }
    
        public void setQuantity(int itemQuantity) {
            this.itemQuantity = itemQuantity;
        }
    
        public int getQuantity() {
            return itemQuantity;
        }
    
        public void printItemPurchase() {
            System.out.println(itemQuantity + " " + itemName + " $" + itemPrice +
                    " = $" + (itemPrice * itemQuantity));
        }
    }
```

Output :

```
Item 1
Enter the item name: 
item 1
Enter the item price: 
20
Enter the item quantity: 
5

Item 2
Enter the item name: 
item 2
Enter the item price: 
2
Enter the item quantity: 
10

TOTAL COST
item 1 5 @ $20 = $100
item 2 10 @ $2 = $20

Total: $120
```

You had misplaced brackets. Once i fixed it this works. Please make sure you use an IDE and not zybooks

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ShoppingCartPrinter {
   //main method
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      //create object of scanner
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      //variable declaration
      int i = 0;
      String productName;
      int productPrice = 0;
      int productQuantity = 0;
      int cartTotal = 0;

      ItemToPurchase item1 = new ItemToPurchase();
      ItemToPurchase item2 = new ItemToPurchase();

      //get item 1 details
      System.out.println("Item 1");

      System.out.println("Enter the item name: ");
      productName = scnr.nextLine();
      item1.setName(productName);

      System.out.println("Enter the item price: ");
      productPrice = scnr.nextInt();
      item1.setPrice(productPrice);

      System.out.println("Enter the item quantity: ");
      productQuantity = scnr.nextInt();
      item1.setQuantity(productQuantity);

      scnr.nextLine();
      System.out.println("");

      //get item 2 details
      System.out.println("Item 2");

      System.out.println("Enter the item name: ");
      productName = scnr.nextLine();
      item2.setName(productName);

      System.out.println("Enter the item price: ");
      productPrice = scnr.nextInt();
      item2.setPrice(productPrice);

      System.out.println("Enter the item quantity: ");
      productQuantity = scnr.nextInt();
      item2.setQuantity(productQuantity);

      System.out.println("");

      //add cost of item 1 and 2 and print total
      cartTotal = (item1.getQuantity() * item1.getPrice()) + (item2.getQuantity() * item2.getPrice());
      System.out.println("TOTAL COST");
      //cart total is item 1 price * quantity + item 2 price * quantity
      //item 1 info
      int item1Total = item1.getPrice() * item1.getQuantity();
      System.out.println(item1.getName() + " " + item1.getQuantity() + " @ $" + item1.getPrice() + " = $" + item1Total);

      //item 2 info
      int item2Total = item2.getPrice() * item2.getQuantity();
      System.out.println(item2.getName() + " " + item2.getQuantity() + " @ $" + item2.getPrice() + " = $" + item2Total);

      //output total
      System.out.println("");
      System.out.print("Total: $" + cartTotal);

   }

   public static class ItemToPurchase {
      //Private fields - itemName, itemPrice, and itemQuanity
      private String itemName;
      private int itemPrice;
      private int itemQuantity;

      //Default Constructor
      public ItemToPurchase() {
         itemName = "none";
         itemPrice = 0;
         itemQuantity = 0;
      }

      //public member methods
      public void setName(String itemName) {
         this.itemName = itemName;
      }

      public String getName() {
         return itemName;
      }

      public void setPrice(int itemPrice) {
         this.itemPrice = itemPrice;
      }

      public int getPrice() {
         return itemPrice;
      }

      public void setQuantity(int itemQuantity) {
         this.itemQuantity = itemQuantity;
      }

      public int getQuantity() {
         return itemQuantity;
      }

      public void printItemPurchase() {
         System.out.println(itemQuantity + " " + itemName + " $" + itemPrice +
                 " = $" + (itemPrice * itemQuantity));
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't see where I'm assigning a string to an Int.  I'm also not aware of what parseInt means and I'm not sure that we have gone over that yet.

Comment: @JoshuaPelkey see the edit

Comment: ok, This helped me a lot. Thank you. It seems like its always something small sometimes.

Comment: just marked it as answered.

Answer (score 1):

You should use scnr.nextLine() after scnr.nextint(). When you enter a value and then press enter, a newline character is added after your value.

When you use nextInt(), it reads only the integer input and leaves behind the "newline" (\n) character in the input buffer. So, if you use nextLine() immediately after nextInt(), it will consume the leftover newline character, essentially reading an empty line.

You already had nextLine() after you inputted the name. Now you need it after each nextInt().

```
System.out.println("Enter the item quantity: ");
productQuantity = scnr.nextInt();
item1.setQuantity(productQuantity);
scnr.nextLine();  // Consuming leftover newline character
```

Comment: oh. I should have caught that. I didn't see this nor was I getting an error for that.  no. I'm not using an IDE. This is in the zybooks platform. Fixed that, but not the parsing error.

Comment: @JoshuaPelkey, yes

Comment: so like this?
`
      System.out.println("Enter the item price: ");
      productPrice = scnr.nextInt();
      item1.setPrice(productPrice);
      scnr.nextLine();
      
      System.out.println("Enter the item quantity: ");
      productQuantity = scnr.nextInt();
      item1.setQuantity(productQuantity);
      scnr.nextLine();
`

Comment: OK so I went through this and added scnr.nextLine(); after nextInt. still throwing a parsing error.

Comment: @JoshuaPelkey, can you update your code in the post?